# How do I know what's the realm and uri of a site

Tags: python, authentication, urllib2

I want to use python's urllib2 with authentication and I need the realm and uri of a url. How do I get it?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a request for a resource that requires authentication, the server will respond with a 401 status code, and a header that contains the realm:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="the realm"
```

The URI is the URL you're trying to access.

Comment: just figured it out myself. Use Live-Http headers for this purpose